# How to rotate a uilabel in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, rotation, rotatetransform

I want to rotate a uiLabel and pin it to the right hand side of a container.

I add the constraints (trailing label to trailing container)

I then rotate the label:

```
[self.label setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
```

Everything works fine in iOS 7. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

But in iso 8 the label is rotated differently. Here is a screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found that in iOS 8 you need to adjust your constraints when you animate views. Set up an IBOutlet the appropriate NSLayoutConstraints and change their constants before you reposition the view.

Comment: I removed the constraints from the xib at run time and then created them programmatically BEFORE I did the transform. Thank you!